# Convert double to Int, rounded down

Tags: java, type-conversion, rounding

How to convert a `double` value to `int` doing the following:

```
Double If x = 4.97542. Convert to int x = 4.

Double If x = 4.23544. Convert to int x = 4.
```

That is, the answer is always rounding down.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you explicitly **cast** `double` to `int`, the decimal part will be truncated. For example:

```
int x = (int) 4.97542;   //gives 4 only
int x = (int) 4.23544;   //gives 4 only
```

Moreover, you may also use `Math.floor()` method to round values in case you want `double` value in return.

Comment: What does it mean to "loose decimal values"?  Does it give the same numbers as calling `Math.floor()`?

Comment: Casting only rounds down for positive values, you **have** to floor first if your values can be negative.

Answer (score 32):

If the double is a `Double` with capital **D** (a boxed primitive value):

```
Double d = 4.97542;
int i = (int) d.doubleValue();

// or directly:
int i2 = d.intValue();
```

If the double is already a primitive `double`, then you simply cast it:

```
double d = 4.97542;
int i = (int) d;
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is the difference between Double and double ?

Comment: a double is a primitive float point value.  A Double is a Java Object.

Comment: This only works for positive values

Answer (score 5):

```
double myDouble = 420.5;
//Type cast double to int
int i = (int)myDouble;
System.out.println(i);
```

The double value is 420.5 and the application prints out the integer value of 420

Answer (score 2):

Another option either using `Double` or `double` is use `Double.valueOf(double d).intValue();`. Simple and clean

Answer (score -1):

I think I had a better output, especially for a double datatype sorting.

Though this question has been marked answered, perhaps this will help someone else;

```
Arrays.sort(newTag, new Comparator<String[]>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
              final Integer time1 = (int)Integer.valueOf((int) Double.parseDouble(entry1[2]));
              final Integer time2 = (int)Integer.valueOf((int) Double.parseDouble(entry2[2]));
              return time1.compareTo(time2);
         }
    });
```