# How to convert double to int in Android?

Tags: android, integer, double

I just wants to convert from double to int in my UI i am rendering as a double but for the backend i want convert to integer.

```
Double d = 45.56;

OutPut = 4556;
```

Please can anybody tell me how to get the value in this format.

Comment: For your information if you cast `Double` to `int` then the result it `45` not `4556` but if you really want output `4556` then remove `.(dot)` from your `Double` value. `what's wrong?`

Comment: double d = 45.56;
String temp = String.valueOf(d);
if (temp .contains(".")) {
    temp  = temp .replaceAll(".","");
}

Answer (score 38):

Try this way,  [Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280520/convert-double-to-int-rounded-down)

```
double d = 45.56;
int i = (int) d;
```

For better info you can visit [converting double to integer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468730/converting-double-to-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 15):

If you just want to convert the Double to int,

```
Double D = 45.56;
int i = Integer.valueOf(D.intValue());
//here i becomes 45
```

But if you want to remove all decimal numbers and count the whole value,

```
//first convert the Double to String 
double D = 45.56;
String s = String.valueOf(D);
// remove all . (dots) from the String
String str = str.replace(".", "");
//Convert the string back to int
int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
// here i becomes 4556
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Double as object(Wrapper for type double). You need to fist convert it in to string and then int.

```
Double d=4.5;
int  i = Integer.parseInt(d.toString());
```

If you want it in the Integer Object Wrapper then can be written as

```
Integer  i = Integer.parseInt(d.toString());
```

**EDIT**
If you want to get the desired result -
You can go like this-

```
    Double d = 4.5;
    double tempD = d;
    int tempI = (int) tempD * 100;
    //Integer i = tempI;
```

Comment: Oh, I couldn't guess the reason of down voting. Thanks @2Dee  I will keep in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvote, that was not me (otherwise I would have downvoted other similar answers as well). I vote considering the ability of the post to answer the question, which you do ;) Thanks for keeping my remark in mind though, I'm sure you'll realize closing duplicates instead of answering them would increase the quality of the site dramatically, which is what we want ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
double d = 45.56; 
String temp = String.valueOf(d); 
if (temp .contains(".")) { 
    temp = temp .replaceAll(".",""); 
}
// After if you want to convert to integer then
int output = Integer.parseInt(temp);
```